# Minimum Input Voltage of Buck Converter

Tags: buck

How do I determine the minimum voltage for a buck converter to work? For example, in this [Reference Design](http://www.ti.com/lit/df/tidrk45/tidrk45.pdf?ts=1590615980990) the minimum voltage is 166VAC. But what if I want to operate it at 100 VAC? What do I need to modify? In general, what parameters define my minimum input voltage? Input capacitance, controller duty cycle, switching frequency?

Answer (score 1):

buck converters work by storing energy in an inductor, then moving that energy into a grounded capacitor.

Identify the parameters that determine success or failure, including

- switching frequency
- duty cycle
- load current, min and max
- inductor overload current (saturation current, set by core cross section, and the type of material)
- input voltage minimum and maximum
- switching losses in the chopping transistors and the commutation diodes
- ripple voltage in the input "DC"
- input filtering resonances that interact with the switch_reg demand for energy
- parasitic coupling, via fast voltage steps and fast current steps, that upset the regulating feedback circuit; this is a great way to implement some chaotic behavior, and require a bigger input voltage to remain above dropout levels
- issues with very narrow pulse widths, needed as you attempt to operate near the minimum Load currents